# how to set result of BackgroundWorker to TextView

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask, textview

I'm very new to android and cannot get a result from a database into a `TextView` on screen. At the moment my app returns a message after click on a button. I have two `TextView` elements on the screen `txtViewBegin` and `txtViewEind`. From `mySql` (via `php`) i get a string like this `22-02-2014 24-05-2017`, which i split with to an array of `Strings (.split(" "))`.

Can I use `setTextView` from the background worker (onPostExecute?)

or should i do this in my `MainActivity`? Still a noob at this. Sorry.

Here is my `BackgroundWorker`:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker(Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url= "http://*************/****.php";
    if(type.equals("Draai")){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(false);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            //OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            //String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name""UTF-8")// HIER KUN JE VARIABELEN INGEVEN DIE WORDEN GEIMPLEMENTEERD IN HET PHP DOCUMENT
            //bufferedWriter.write();
            //bufferedWriter.flush();
            // bufferedWriter.close();
            //outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result ="";
            String line="";
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                result += line;
            }
            String[] separated = result.split(" ");
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("TijdsDuur");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

and my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView ViewBegin, ViewEind;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewBegin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewBegin);
    ViewEind = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewEind);
}

public void onDraai(View view){
    String type = "Draai";

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) create an `interface` for callback in your `BackgroundWorker`

```
public interface DataCallBack{
     void onDataReceived(String s);
}
```

2.) Implement that callback interface in your `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BackgroundWorker.DataCallBack {
```

3.) When the task is done , notify your activity with data to display

Your `MainActivity` will look like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BackgroundWorker.DataCallBack {
TextView ViewBegin, ViewEind;

  // .....code

    @Override
    void onDataReceived(String s){
         if(s!=null){
            String[] separated = result.split(" ");
            ViewBegin.setText(separated[0]);  
            ViewEind.setText(separated[1]);  
         }    
    }

  // .....code

}
```

Your `BackgroundWorker` class will look like

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    DataCallBack callback;

    BackgroundWorker(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;

        // initialize the callback reference
        callback = (DataCallBack) cxt;
    }

    public interface DataCallBack{
         void onDataReceived(String s);
    }

    // .....code

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        callback.onDataReceived(result);
        // ^^^ send data to Activity

        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    // .....code

}
```